# How can I decide at runtime which derived class to use as a private class member in C++?

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, virtual

This following question is a bit hard for me to formulate, but please bear with me, and let me know if I can help in clearing anything up.

I am writing a general-purpose simulation for 3D shapes. I am using a base class:

```
class Shape{
    public:
    ...
        virtual double return_volume() =0;
    private:
        vector<double> coordinates;
    ...
};
```

Now, since I don't know what shape the user will choose, I derive several classes from this. (e.g.: Sphere, Cube, Tetrahedron, etc.)

So far, everything is fine.
The main problem comes in the form that I have a Controller class, which launches and operates the simulation. As a private member, it should have a vector of multiple shapes (all of the same type. e.g.: 15 spheres, or 10 cubes, etc.)

```
class SimulationControl{
    public:
        void runsimulation();
    private:
        vector<Shape> all_shapes;
    ...
};
```

I wanted to simply initialize this private member with a non-default constructor.
Now, before I knew what I had done, Eclipse already told me that "The type 'Shape' must implement the inherited pure virtual method 'Shape::return_volume'"

I understand the error message and my mistake, of course, but I still don't understand how I can solve it.

What I would love to be able to do is to leave the type of vector undefined, and then simply create it via the constructor with the correct derived class at runtime, when I know which type of simulation the user chose.

Is is somehow possible to do that? Thanks

Comment: You could do it by storing a pointer (e.g. `Shape*` in the vector) but that has memory management implications.

Comment: Use [polymophism](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/polymorphism/) You can use smart pointers to manage memory for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not going to jump on the bandwagon and suggest using pointers in your container, whether smart or dumb. This is the perfect opportunity to use the [PIMPL idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pimpl_idiom).

The idea is that the class is simply a wrapper for the actual implementation, and calls a pointer to another object when a call is made to it. The pointer contained within the wrapper can be polymorphic so that it can implement the functions however it sees fit.

```
class Shape{
    public:
        Shape() { pImpl = NULL; }
        Shape(const Shape& from) { pImpl = from.pImpl->clone(); }
        ~Shape() { delete pImpl; }
        Shape& operator=(const Shape& from) { pImpl = from.pImpl->clone(); }
    ...
        double return_volume() { return pImpl->return_volume(); }
    private:
        ShapeImpl * pImpl;
    ...
};

class ShapeImpl{
    public:
    ...
        virtual ShapeImpl* clone() const =0;
        virtual double return_volume() =0;
    private:
        vector<double> coordinates;
    ...
};
```

Because the `Shape` class contains a pointer you'll need to implement the [rule of three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29) and create a destructor, copy constructor, and `operator=`. The defaults for the copies will certainly do the wrong thing - they'll only copy the pointer value without creating a new copy of the pimpl object to go with them. Since a `vector` copies elements around these functions are certain to get called.

Comment: You should warn him about making copies of Shape then if he is going to store them in a vector.

Comment: @BrianNeal, very good point, thanks. I've added the warning but I should have added code; I just don't have time at the moment to do a careful job and I'm afraid of leaving something misleading.

Comment: Hi Mark! Thank you very much for your post. I've marked this as the "correct" answer.
Thank you also for your warnings. I admit that this may be above my level, but even I can see that I am walking on quicksand with pointers to vectors in classes.
I will try to implement it as you suggested, but have a question too:
ShapeImpl is basically the old "Shape", correct? And the new Shape is basically what I can use with the controller class, did I get that righ?

Comment: Another thing I just found out. I made the copy constructor using Shape(const Shape& from_here) : pImpl(new ShapeImpl(*from_here.pImpl)), but this gives me the same error message that stopped me in the first place. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: @MarkAnderson, this is why I thought it would be best to update my example with more code. Your ShapeImpl class should implement a virtual `clone` method which creates a copy of the most derived class instead of the base class.

Comment: @MarkRansom Thank you for your hep thus far, since I understand that your time is limited. I admit that I still don't understand how I can make this work, as a virtual clone function gives me the same trouble, but I will try to do some research on my own, or maybe try to use the smart pointer approach, I may have more luck there.

Comment: @MarkRansom, Thank you so much for your edit. This cleared things up immensely. If I could give you any more upvotes, I would. Kudos to you, and I hope I may be able to help you at some point in the future.

Answer (score 2):

**Use (smart) pointers**.

You cannot instantiate an abstract class, and even if you could, that would probably not be what you want, since you wouldn't be able to create *aliases* of those shapes.

You should change the definition of your `SimulationControl` class into something more similar to this (assuming shared ownership for your shapes here - if `SimulationControl` is the only owner of your shapes, rather use `unique_ptr` instead of `shared_ptr`):

```
#include <memory>

class SimulationControl {
    public:
        void runsimulation();
    private:

        std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Shape>> all_shapes;
    ...
};
```

Then, you could create instances of your shapes and add them to the `all_shapes` collection as follows (supposing `MyShape` is a concrete, default-constructible class derived from `Shape`):

```
std::shared_ptr<MyShape> pShape = std::make_shared<MyShape>();

pShape->set_vertices(...); // I guess the class will have a member function
                           // that allows setting the shape's vertices...

all_shapes.push_back(pShape);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only do polymorphism by pointer or reference. Try using `vector<Shape*>`.

Now that you are using pointers you'll have to manage the memory for them, but that is another set of questions. Try to use smart pointers if you can, or be very careful if you can't. If you are using C++11, `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Shape>>` might fit the bill for you.